# Optimize MySQL Queries with Group-Function and two different Timestamps with Join

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have got to different tables with temperature values and a timestamp. I join those tables with this query:

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(l.TimeDate) time
     , AVG(l.intemp)
     , AVG(n.intemp)
     , DATE_FORMAT(l.TimeDate, '%Y-%m-%d-%H') dates 
  FROM values.temps l 
  LEFT 
  JOIN values.net n
    ON DATE_FORMAT(l.TimeDate, '%Y-%m-%d-%H') = DATE_FORMAT(n.TimeDate, '%Y-%m-%d-%H') 
 WHERE YEARWEEK('2017-01-17 00:00:00',1) = YEARWEEK(l.TimeDate,1) 
 GROUP 
    BY dates 
 ORDER 
    BY dates ASC
```

This query is a little bit slow, but it works and gives me the values for 1 week. So how can I optimize it?

Comment: The slow bits are the join and the where - neither of which can use an index. Rewrite them so that they can - I forget what H is!?!

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for the answer. But i have got an index. so i don't know how to do it better.

Comment: Functions can't use indexes. So, if you want to use indexes, you have to think of a way to remove the functions. This is normally done with a range query. I might try to post an example...

Comment: Thanks a lot. This sounds good

Comment: Hi, is there anyone how can send me an optimized version. The both tables are really big with nearly 100.000 rows and they are getting bigger :)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't responded because actually I'm struggling to think how to express your YEARWEEK condition in terms of a range query.

I thought something like this would work, but it refuses to use 'range'.

```
SELECT * 
  FROM my_table 
 WHERE dt BETWEEN CONCAT(STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(YEARWEEK('2017-01-25'), ' Monday'), '%x%v %W'), ' 00:00:00') 
              AND CONCAT(STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(YEARWEEK('2017-01-25'), ' Sunday'), '%x%v %W'), ' 23:59:59')
```

Perhaps others can spot my schoolboy error.

```
+----+-------------+----------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table    | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+----------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | my_table | ALL  | dt            | NULL | NULL    | NULL |  100 | Using where |
+----+-------------+----------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------------+
```

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for the answer. I hope someone can help. But thanks a lot for your help.